# how to implement pagination in flutter using dio

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am trying to implement pagination in my flutter app. I have organized my data using MVVM architecture, in this way -

`search_view.dart` - It contains the `listview` which will be visible to User. First, it call a method `initilize`, which initializes the bus list and store it in `itemBusList` variable. It takes the list from - `model.itemBusList` (A list of type Datum), and use it with `ListView.builder`.

`search_model.dart` - It contains the variable `itemBusList` and has the function -

```
fetchBuses() async {
    tripsResponse = await (_databaseService.requestTrips(
      object: object!,
    ));
    setBusy(false);
    if (tripsResponse?.data != null) {
      itemBusList.clear();
      itemBusList.addAll(tripsResponse?.data.data);
      notifyListeners();
    }
    else {
      itemBusList.clear();
      //empty list
    }
  }
```

It is fetching data using -

```
tripsResponse = await (_databaseService.requestTrips(
      object: object!,
    ));
```

`_databaseService` is a variable of type `DatabaseService`.

`databse_service.dart` - It is mainly a connecting line between fetching api and storing/converting data in a useful manner. I use this `requestTrips` for fetching my bus data -

```
Future<BaseData?> requestTrips({
    required TripRequestDto object,
  }) async {
    Response response = await _apiService.handlePost(
      body: object.toMap(),
      type: FetchDataType.TRIP_REQUEST_DTO_RESPONSE,
    );
    return response.data;
  }
```

Here, _apiService is an object of type `ApiService`, the class which handles api calls.

```
api_service.dart - 

Future<Response<BaseData<dynamic>>> handlePost({
    Map<String, dynamic>? body,
    Map<String, dynamic>? parameters,
    Map<String, dynamic>? extras,
    FetchDataType? type,
  }) async {
    Dio dioNetwork;

    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> requiredData = await fetchCredentials(type, extras);

      dioNetwork = initDioObject(requiredData['version'], type);

      return await dioNetwork.post(
        requiredData['path'],
        queryParameters: parameters,
        data: body,
        options: Options(headers: getHeaders(requiredData)),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print('got an error while api call');
      Response<BaseData<dynamic>> response =
          Response(requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''));
      response.data = BaseData(
          success: false,
          data: null,
          message: _setErrorMessage(e as DioError),
          statusCode: serverError(e));
      return response;
    }
  }
```

Now, how can I get the responses in 5 at a time, and continue till the end. I want that 5 elements should appear for pagination at a time, and as I refresh, 5 more and continue. I am new to this, please help me.

Here is the datum class -

```
class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.trip,
    this.nodes,
    this.vehicle,
    this.canPolicy,
    this.cashBookAllowed,
    this.bookAllowed,
    this.reschedulePolicy,
    //this.totalPages,
  });

  Trip? trip;
  List<NodeElement>? nodes;
  Vehicle? vehicle;
  Policy? canPolicy;
  bool? cashBookAllowed;
  bool? bookAllowed;
  Policy? reschedulePolicy;
  //int? totalPages;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        trip: json["trip"] == null ? null : Trip.fromJson(json["trip"]),
        nodes: json["nodes"] == null
            ? null
            : List<NodeElement>.from(
                json["nodes"].map((x) => NodeElement.fromJson(x))),
        vehicle:
            json["vehicle"] == null ? null : Vehicle.fromJson(json["vehicle"]),
        canPolicy: json["canPolicy"] == null
            ? null
            : Policy.fromJson(json["canPolicy"]),
        cashBookAllowed:
            json["cashBookAllowed"] == null ? null : json["cashBookAllowed"],
        bookAllowed: json["bookAllowed"] == null ? null : json["bookAllowed"],
        reschedulePolicy: json["reschedulePolicy"] == null
            ? null
            : Policy.fromJson(json["reschedulePolicy"]),
        //totalPages: json["totalPages"] == null ? null : json["totalPages"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "trip": trip == null ? null : trip!.toJson(),
        "nodes": nodes == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(nodes!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "vehicle": vehicle == null ? null : vehicle!.toJson(),
        "canPolicy": canPolicy == null ? null : canPolicy!.toJson(),
        "cashBookAllowed": cashBookAllowed == null ? null : cashBookAllowed,
        "bookAllowed": bookAllowed == null ? null : bookAllowed,
        "reschedulePolicy":
            reschedulePolicy == null ? null : reschedulePolicy!.toJson(),
        //"page" : totalPages == null ? null : totalPages
      };
}
```

Here is the class trip -

```
class Trip {
  Trip({
    this.tripId,
    this.origin,
    this.dest,
    this.code,
    this.timeSlot,
    this.schStart,
    this.schEnd,
    this.minPrice,
    this.minBasePrice,
    this.freeSeats,
    this.totalKm,
    this.vehicleTypeId,
    this.nonStop,
    this.status,
    this.serviceId,
  });

  int? tripId;
  Dest? origin;
  Dest? dest;
  String? code;
  int? timeSlot;
  int? schStart;
  int? schEnd;
  double? minPrice;
  double? minBasePrice;
  int? freeSeats;
  int? totalKm;
  int? vehicleTypeId;
  bool? nonStop;
  StatusClass? status;
  String? serviceId;

  factory Trip.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Trip(
        tripId: json["tripId"] == null ? null : json["tripId"],
        origin: json["origin"] == null ? null : Dest.fromJson(json["origin"]),
        dest: json["dest"] == null ? null : Dest.fromJson(json["dest"]),
        code: json["code"] == null ? null : json["code"],
        timeSlot: json["timeSlot"] == null ? null : json["timeSlot"],
        schStart: json["schStart"] == null ? null : json["schStart"],
        schEnd: json["schEnd"] == null ? null : json["schEnd"],
        minPrice: json["minPrice"] == null ? null : json["minPrice"],
        minBasePrice:
            json["minBasePrice"] == null ? null : json["minBasePrice"],
        freeSeats: json["freeSeats"] == null ? null : json["freeSeats"],
        totalKm: json["totalKM"] == null ? null : json["totalKM"],
        vehicleTypeId:
            json["vehicleTypeId"] == null ? null : json["vehicleTypeId"],
        nonStop: json["nonStop"] == null ? null : json["nonStop"],
        status: json["status"] == null
            ? null
            : StatusClass.fromJson(json["status"]),
        serviceId: json["serviceId"] == null ? null : json["serviceId"],
      );
```

Comment: Does your API support pagination?

Comment: Yes, it does. How should I implement?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to add parameters to query in request. Similar like this:

```dart
_apiService.handlePost(
  body: object.toMap(),
  type: FetchDataType.TRIP_REQUEST_DTO_RESPONSE,
  parameters: {
    'limit': 10,
    'offset': 0,
  }
)
```

Where `limit` and `offset` is an equivalent of pagination parameters from your API. Also, you need to store limit and offset values in local variables.

Comment: And can I do pagination if these parameters are not coming? I mean, can I manually make the call to fetch 10 list items at a time, and then when request is made again, next 10 and so on

Comment: You can use [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) plugin for it or write your own solution.

Comment: I tried, but was not able to achieve it. Can you help me out

Comment: Are you facing problems in API implementation or in UI realization?

Comment: I am stuck on how to make api call, such that only 5 items are loaded at a time and when called again, next 5 and so on.., respective of the fact that my api doesn't support pagination by itself

Comment: Can you add some API specs from your API?

Comment: I have edited the post, you can check the classes, whose objects are being used, and see if that helps. I am not sure what are API specs tbh.

Comment: Are you has an requirements in your API? Docs or other source.